# change icon_image of google marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to change the marker image in a particular scenario. When we click on one of the marker of the map having multiple marker, on click it will opens a pop-up, pop-up contains  2-3 fields and submit button. When we click that submit button after that i wants to change marker image. Please let me know how to do that. I have tried from below link but it change image before we submit button of popup.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.setIcon("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/24/Stock%20Index%20Down.png");
    }
})(marker, i));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gargiguy/s8vgxp3g/

Comment: changed link and wrote code pls help

Comment: There is no submit button in the infowindows in your example.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

To change the marker after the button click, add a function that runs on the click of the button. Pass that function a reference to the marker and use that to change the icon.

One option:  create an array of markers (i.e. `gmarkers`), push the markers on to that array, then use the array index of the marker to change its icon:

```
window.submitFunction = function(i) {
    gmarkers[i].setIcon("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/24/Stock%20Index%20Down.png");
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s8vgxp3g/68/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers = [];

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    // center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.8857, -76.2599),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var iconBase = 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/24/';
  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: iconBase + 'Stock%20Index%20Up.png'
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        console.log(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][6] + "<br><input id='btn' value='submit' type='button' onclick='submitFunction(" + (gmarkers.length - 1) + ");/>");
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][6] + "<br><input id='btn' value='submit' type='button' onclick='submitFunction(" + i + ");'/>");
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}
window.submitFunction = function(i) {
  gmarkers[i].setIcon("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/24/Stock%20Index%20Down.png");

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
var locations = [
  [
    "New Mermaid",
    36.9079, -76.199,
    1,
    "Georgia Mason",
    "",
    "Norfolk Botanical Gardens, 6700 Azalea Garden Rd.",
    "coming soon"
  ],
  [
    "1950 Fish Dish",
    36.87224, -76.29518,
    2,
    "Terry Cox-Joseph",
    "Rowena's",
    "758 W. 22nd Street in front of Rowena's",
    "found"
  ],
  [
    "A Rising Community",
    36.95298, -76.25158,
    3,
    "Steven F. Morris",
    "Judy Boone Realty",
    "Norfolk City Library - Pretlow Branch, 9640 Granby St.",
    "found"
  ],
  [
    "A School Of Fish",
    36.88909, -76.26055,
    4,
    "Steven F. Morris",
    "Sandfiddler Pawn Shop",
    "5429 Tidewater Dr.",
    "found"
  ],
  [
    "Aubrica the Mermaid (nee: Aubry Alexis)",
    36.8618, -76.203,
    5,
    "Myke Irving/ Georgia Mason",
    "USAVE Auto Rental",
    "Virginia Auto Rental on Virginia Beach Blvd",
    "found"
  ]
];
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks geocodezip

could u please help me in also different  scenario  like on click marker it will open list of button when we click one of them it will open another for on click of that button (<button>) i suppose to change icon of google map. i am not able find how to bind click event to that button.

Comment: That is a different question.  If this answered your question, solved the issue, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)